# Mario level that is completely RNG

Tags: probability

If a level is only beatable in a random number generator kind of way and has a probability of 1 in 7.5 million chance of occurring and each attempt to successfully do that something takes about 8 seconds, what is the most probable amount of time it would take for completion of the level to occur?

Comment: What does it mean for a level to be only beatable "in a random number generator kind of way"? When you say "each attempt to successfully do that something takes about 8 seconds", what does "that something" refer to?

Comment: @littleO There is this game called Super Mario Maker where players can make their own Mario-like stages. Although there are few non-deterministic parts available, stages have been constructed where the player (i.e. Mario) can do nothing but hope that they reach the end of the level due to random objects - they die if the luck doesn't go their way.

Comment: Most probable amount of time or rather expected time? Have a look at the [expected numer of failures before the first success](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution#Expected_number_of_failures_before_the_first_success)

Comment: Depending on the way that Mario Maker generates random numbers (some sort of modulo calculations), it is possible that you don't have any chance of completing the level.

Answer (score 3):

What you are probably asking for is the expected number of trials until you have a success in your random experiment.

That is $7.5$ million.

So the expected time until you pass the Mario level is $7.5*8$ million seconds. See the link specified by Markus Ritt in the comments for information on why this is the answer.

If you are indeed asking about the mode(most probable amount of time it would take for the completion of the level to occur) then the answer is $8$ seconds.

Notice that the probability of completing the level in $8$ seconds(that is in your first try) is:

$P(time=8)=\frac{1}{7500000}$

The probability of completing the level in $16$ seconds is equal to the probability of not completing the level in the first try and completing it in the second trial, so:

$P(time=16)=\frac{7499999}{7500000}*\frac{1}{7500000} < \frac{1}{7500000}$

Continuing this way you can see that $P(time=8)>P(time=16)>P(time=24)$ and so on. So the mode for $time$ is the value $8$ (although this isn't probably what you are asking for).

Generally speaking mode is not very useful in this situation because even though it is the most probable value, it is still to little and not many(almost none) players will complete the level in this time.